# Docker containers exiting due to supervisor

Tags: docker, supervisord

I've built an image from Ubuntu 18 as base image.
It has multiple service like nginx, php-fpm and ssh installed.

Everything was working, the container was getting created, I could access the container and everything related to a container.

But I had to manually start nginx and php-fpm by going inside the container. I did a little google search and came up with supervisor.

So I added supervisor scripts to start the services automatically. But since adding the supervisor, my container is getting exited as soon as it is created.

On checking the container logs with command `docker logs container-name` I am getting error:

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:297:
>   UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for
>   its configuration file in default locations (including its current
>   working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument
>   specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved
>   security.   'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '

In my Dockerfile, supervisor code is like this:

```
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
.
.
.
.
COPY ./supervisor/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
COPY ./supervisor/sshd.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/sshd.conf
COPY ./supervisor/nginx.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/nginx.conf
COPY ./supervisor/php-fpm.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/php-fpm.conf
.
.
.
.
CMD supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

I've done a lot of google search and couldn't solve the problem. I'll be really grateful if someone could help to solve this problem. Let me know if any other information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

In your supervisord.conf, add this:

[supervisord]

nodaemon=true

This instructs supervisord to start in the foreground and not as a service. I had the same problem, but this line solved it.

I got it from [this](https://advancedweb.hu/2018/07/03/supervisor_docker/).